# Create View and For Json clause

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

With `SQL Server 2016`, I can run this simple query:

```
SELECT  colA, colB, json_query(infoJson) AS Expr1
FROM    dbo.Table_1 
FOR     json auto
```

I can even wrap it in a stored procedure. And it runs nicely.

But when I tried to create a view out of that statement, something weird (at least to me):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT   colA, colB, json_query(infoJson) AS Expr1
FROM     dbo.Table_1 
FOR      json auto
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 4511, Level 16, State 1, Procedure View_1, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 1.

But as soon as I comment `--for json auto`, the `VIEW` is created as expected.

Why? I'd really like it to have have `FOR JSON` in my sql view.

Comment: Your view wants you to name the json column something.

Comment: it is not that. Point is that I am nt able to apply 'for json' into a view.

Comment: the error is misleading

Comment: I need to correct myself when I say '...created as expected' View is just created but not as expected since FOR JSON will make a difference

Answer (score 5):

`FOR XML | JSON AUTO` returns a single column (character LOB). So you need to modify the SELECT statement to return a single column in the view like:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT (
SELECT   colA, colB, json_query(infoJson) AS Expr1
FROM     dbo.Table_1 
FOR      json auto
) as X
```

Comment: That's a brilliant technique for getting around the problem with SSMS wrapping the result of a SQL For JSON query - this needs to be known more widely. - Top work

Answer (score 4):

You can add column(s) to the create view statement:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
(column_name)
AS
    SELECT colA, colB, json_query(infoJson) AS Expr1
      FROM dbo.Table_1 
       FOR json auto
```

Comment: wow I've been a DBA/Dev for a minute and didn't know you could add columns to a view like that. Very nice. Why isn't this the answer??